# String Calculator in Android

Tags: android, string

I am trying to create string calculator in Android, here is my function;

```
public void hesapla(View view) {

    islemString = Islem.getText().toString();

    List<String> operatorList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> operandList = new ArrayList<String>();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(islemString, "+-*/()", true);

    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String token = st.nextToken();

        if ("+-/*()".contains(token)) {
            operatorList.add(token);
        } else {
            operandList.add(token);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i>=20; i++) {
        if (operatorList.get(i) == "(") {
            int a=0;
            while(operatorList.get(a) == ")"){

                if(operatorList.get(a+1) == "+"){
                    sonucDouble = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(operandList.get(i))) + Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(operandList.get(i+1)));
                }

                if(operatorList.get(a+1) == "-"){
                    sonucDouble = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(operandList.get(i))) - Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(operandList.get(i+1)));
                }

                if(operatorList.get(a+1) == "*"){
                    sonucDouble = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(operandList.get(i))) * Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(operandList.get(i+1)));
                }

                if(operatorList.get(a+1) == "/"){
                    sonucDouble = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(operandList.get(i))) / Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(operandList.get(i+1)));
                }
                a++;
            }
        }
    }
```

When clicked Calculate button, i am getting operand to List and operator to List each of one. But i can't read again.

```
if (operatorList.get(i) == "(")
```

I am trying this, but where is my wrong? How i can? Thank you.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `Java/Android` Object comparison should use `equals()` instead of `==` (as best practice to avoid `NullPointerException`, use constants first while comparing `String`).

Example:

```
if ("(".equals(operatorList.get(i)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `for` loop that will never execute

```
for(int i=0; i>=20; i++) {
    if (operatorList.get(i) == "(") {
```

You start with `i=0` and condition for looping is `i>=20` which is not true. Try

```
for(int i=0; i<=20; i++) {
    if (operatorList.get(i) == "(") {
```

and then see if your code moves forward

Answer (score 0):

I think you need changes the code when compare String,

```
if (operatorList.get(i).equals("(")))
```

And changes too for other